# Speed up wordpress website rewriting some functions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have Wordpress based website and on every page it generates many queries.

Some queries goes to the same tables like

```
select something from table where name = 1
select something from table where name = 2
select something from table where name = 3
```

Some of them are WP core functions, some goes from functions.php of used theme

The problem is: I can not find if there is a way to get this data in one query.

To rewrite WP core based queries I can use WP_Query but what about functions.php of theme file?

Can i rewrite it or extend it? Will there be any problems if I modify it by hand? (Like I SHOULD NEVER modify WP core by hand but is this the same with theme?)

Comment: Then you have quite a bit of research to do

Comment: Yes, you can use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)